# MySQL Driver for PHP PDO

Tags: mysql, php, php5, 64-bit

Are PDO drivers available for download for Win64?  I'm looking for a MySQL driver, but all my Googling seems to suggest that my PHP binary should have been compiled with this support.  Is that the case?

Any idea where I can find a late version of PHP that is built for 64-bit on Windows that includes support for MySQL with PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently no PDO drivers specifically for Win64, nor is there a 64 bit version of PHP generally available. The 32 bit versions of both work fine for me though.